# Find the family of polygons such that the sum of all unit normals is $0$

Tags: geometry, vectors

Consider an arbitrary 2D polygon. I define the unit normal of a side of the polygon the vector orthogonal to the side of the polygon and pointing outward, of length one.

I want to know what is the family of polygons such that the vector sum of all unit normals of the polygon amount to zero.

For example, we know that a rectangle would be in this family, because the opposite normals cancel out. However, an isosceles trapezoid would not fulfill this rule, because the sum would be positive in the direction of the smaller base.

What is this family? Are there any interesting properties in this family? I do not require that the polygon should be convex.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: If all internal angles are equal, then the sum of unit normals is zero. However, that's not all of them, as a parallelogram also has zero sum.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I suspect that this property has to do with some kind of symmetry with the horizontal and the vertical (edit: i forgot about the parallelogram, thanks Arthur ) . However, I don't know how I would express this in a compact way such that the properties would be evident.

Comment: No idea what is that family. However, it has nothing to do with symmetry. any equilateral polygon (i.e. all sides has same length) with have  their outward unit normal sum to zero.

Comment: Maybe it is about symmetry around two or more axes not necessarily orthogonal. The parallelogram is symmetric with respect to two axes not orthogonal. Also, the equilateral triangle is symmetric with respect to three axes.

Answer (score 1):

*Convex polygon set*

$n$ number of of regularly oriented / spaced in ($\theta=  \pi/n ) $ interval vectors $F$ add up to zero.

The zero sum is seen trigonomically *either* using formula  ang $y$ ox $x$ direction.

$$ \sin (1  \pi/n )+\sin (2  \pi/n ) + ... +  \sin ( n\cdot2 \pi/n )=0 $$

$$ \cos (1  \pi/n )+\cos (2  \pi/n ) + ... +  \cos ( n\cdot2 \pi/n )=0 $$

*or*

graphically in a vector diagram with vectors connecting end to end along variable directions tangent to a circle of radius $F$. For example $n=8$
[image: Polygon Forces]

The vectors can be placed either at end of each vertex or at middle point of each side of regular polygon, the $n-$gon

$$ \Sigma_1^n F \cos \theta_i =0 ;\, \Sigma_1^n F \sin \theta_j =0  $$

The above is a statement of static equilibrium of rotating forces $F_{i}$. $F$ can have any value including unity.

In Three dimensional force equilibrium we can assign directions to each directed area of a Platonic solid which are further amenable to trigonometric generalization by integrals/sums to zero now in *three* mutually perpendicular directions.

*Non-convex polygons set*

A non convex set is obtained by *superposition of two* or more convex sets.

we have  for $x$ or $y$ vector balance in each direction

$$ \Sigma_1^{n} F_i \sin \theta_i =0 , \Sigma_1^{n} F_k \sin \theta_k =0 , $$

where $k$ is a multiple of $i$.